# Question about the home and root directory relationship

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, partitioning

I keep seeing this graph showing up in the Ubuntu community
[image]

which leads to my question: From the graph, it seems that `/home` $\subset$ `/`, meaning `/home` is stored under `/`. However, when I did partition during the installation, I set separate partitions for `/` and `/home`. How does the storage system work in this case? Does the `/home` folder have its own storage place, which is the partition `/home`, while the rest of the folders in the `/` are stored in the `/` partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/home`-directory resides in the `/`-partition. It's the content of the `/home`-directory which is stored on a separate partition. This partition is then mounted at `/home`, the `/home`-directory is used as mountpoint.

All the folders which are light blue coloured in your picture reside in the `/`-partition, although there contents may reside on a separate partition. A popular example is a boot-partition, a partition mounted at `/boot`, but the `/boot`-directory resides in the `/`-partition.

Comment: So the /home-directory is only a "place holder" that resides in the /-partition and points to another partition, is that it? Does /home-partition store all the content of the ~(the ~ appears in the command line)? Are all the contents other than the ones in the /home-directory stored in the /-partition? It seems to me the partition and the file system are not the same ideas, but if we name the partition as "/" and "home", they will be automatically referred to the /-directory and /home-directory, is it correct?

Comment: In a way, `/home` is a placeholder, like you wrote, but in fact it is a real directory. Take a look at `/etc/fstab`, in this file we define which partition to mount where. If you use a separate home-partition all it's content is stored in this partition. `~` is not `/home`, it is `/home/user`. Indeed partitions are not the same as filesystems. A partition is just defined diskspace. A partition acts as a container for a filesystem. The filesystem is what gets mounted, but in dayly life we also say the partition gets mounted.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the /home folder have its own storage place, which is the
> partition /home, while the rest of the folders in the / are stored in
> the / partition?

Yes, exactly. You can get a confirmation with the terminal command:

```
df -H
```

You might see something like:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           802M  3.8M  798M   1% /run
/dev/sda1       108G   23G   80G  22% /
tmpfs           4.1G   24M  4.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda6       870G  654G  172G  80% /home
```

In this example, the / partition is on sda1 and the /home partition is sda6.

Within /home, you will have one or more user directories; for example *chili* so /home/chili. Within /home/chili, you can set any storage directories you want; for example, Photos, Music, Downloads, etc.

All system changes, updates, etc., automatically find and use / on, in my example, sda1, without any user intervention.

Comment: No, the `/home`-folder always resides in the `/`-partition, no way around. It's the content of `/home` which may be stored on a different partition.

Comment: @mook765 That is correct. Even if `/dev/sda6` is not mounted, there is still a directory `/home`, but it's empty.